# From a click handler, how do you detect whether the click formed a selection or not?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In my application, clicking on the caption div for a window minimizes it, and clicking on the body of the window focuses the input control.  However, if the user selects some text, the browser still fires the click event.  How do I distinguish between click events that eliminate a selection and those that form a selection?  I tried checking `window.getSelection().isCollapsed` but that is still set to true in the handler if there was a selection and the click clears the selection.

Is there a correct way to do this?

**EDIT**: This might be a Chrome bug.  The behavior works exactly as I want in Firefox.  See the example code here https://jsfiddle.net/tL3obf7q/

**EDIT 2**: Chrome bug after all!  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=289763

Comment: **DOM**: on text input and textarea you can add `onselect` event as exception to this trigger;

Comment: **jQuery**: on text input and textarea you can add `select()` event as exception to this trigger;

Comment: `window.getSelection().isCollapsed` is meant to be `true` when the selection has been cleared by clicking, so I'm not sure I understand your problem. Please share your code.

Comment: @pawel Thanks, it turned out to be a Chrome/WebKit bug. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=289763 Glad to know I was doing the right thing!